# How count cells without range and some criterion using excell

Tags: excel, count, countif

I hope, I can help me!

I have a data frame as this:

```
        A       B       C       D       E       F     G
1       4       2       3       0       0       0    (Here the formula)         
2       0       0       0       0       0       0    (Here the formula)
3       3       2       4       5       0       0    (Here the formula)
4       0       0       0       0       5       2    (Here the formula)
5       0       0       0       5       5       5    (Here the formula)
```

in column G, a counting formula must be according to the following criteria: With <>:distinct of

I have sum the count(if(A2<>0 and A3<>0) + (B2 and B3)....

for example: I tried to make this;

in G1

```
=SUM(COUNT(IF(AND(A1<>0;A2<>0);1;0);COUNT(IF(AND(B1<>0;B2<>0);1;0);COUNT(IF(AND(C1<>0;C2<>0);1;0).....COUNT(IF(AND(F1<>0;F2<>0);1;0);COUNT(IF(AND(A1<>0;A3<>0);1;0);COUNT(IF(AND(B1<>0;B3<>0);1;0);COUNT(IF(AND(C1<>0;C3<>0);1;0).....COUNT(IF(AND(F1<>0;F3<>0);1;0);............
COUNT(IF(AND(A1<>0;A5<>0);1;0);COUNT(IF(AND(B1<>0;B5<>0);1;0);COUNT(IF(AND(C1<>0;C5<>0);1;0).....COUNT(IF(AND(F1<>0;F5<>0);1;0))
```

for each G2, G3,...G5

that is to say, I want to count only the cells in which there are only non-zero values in the same column and add them, it would be something like this:

```
G1 is equal to:
       
= (0 + 3 + 0 + 0)

G2 is equal to:
       
= (0 + 0 + 0 + 0)

G3 is equal to:
       
= (3 + 0 + 0 + 1)

G4 is equal to:
       
= (0 + 0 + 0 + 0)

G4 is equal to:
       
= (0 + 0 + 1 + 2)
```

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in G1:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:F1<>0)*($A$1:$F$5<>0)*(ROW($A$1:$F$5)<>ROW(A1:F1)))
```

And copy down.

[image]

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could explain to me how this formula works or guide me to some references. I've never seen anybody use this notation `A1:F1<>0` before, looks very interesting - I did not know that one could include conditions inside of `=SUMPRODUCT()`

Comment: Let me try: it 'sumproducts' the first row with all rows in the table, but only the cells which are different than zero, and also (the last condition with the ROW()) it only sumproducts all the rows which are different than the current row? Is that about right? :P